# Equivalent of R array in Python

Tags: python, r, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to find the Python equivalent to R's `array` function is when called in the following manner.

```
array(rep(1, 16), dim = rep(2, 4))
```

This results in:

```
, , 1, 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1

, , 2, 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1

, , 1, 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1

, , 2, 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1
```

Comment: Please check numpy.

Comment: Not preserve the same final dimension as R

Comment: you want R code?

Comment: Please check numpy.full

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
np.full((2,2,2, 2), 1)
```

Please check this.